# AJAX-Request: Access-Control-Allow-Header doesn't allow X-CSRFToken

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a little question on an ajax-request.
In my code I want to access a php-script which 'grabs' some content via an ajax-call. You can see the jQuery-code below:

```
<div id="ajaxcontent"></div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.vhb.wiwi.uni-wuerzburg.de/bp1/wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.vhb.wiwi.uni-wuerzburg.de/bp1/wp/contentgrabber/contentgrabber.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: "page_id=73&ajax=1",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data){
            $("#ajaxcontent").html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The URL works fine, so by clicking onto, it show's me the stuff I want to load. The problem is, that I get the following two Errors:
[image: the two errors i get when running the code]

Somehow my server doesn't seem to allow some kind of X-CSRFToken. Unfortunatelly I have no great experience with that kind of requests, but I think that something more has to be changed in the php-file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");


if(isset($_GET["page_id"]))
{
    $page_id=$_GET["page_id"];

    $url = "http://www.vhb.wiwi.uni-wuerzburg.de/bp1/wp/?page_id=".$_GET["page_id"];

    $website_content = file_get_contents($url);

    $part_1 = substr($website_content, strpos($website_content, "<!-- CONTENTGRABBER_START -->")-27);
    $content = substr($part_1,27, strpos($part_1, "<!-- CONTENTGRABBER_END -->"));

    $part_2 = substr($website_content, strpos($website_content, "<!-- CONTENT_STYLE_GRABBER_START -->")-36);
    $content_style = substr($part_2,36, strpos($part_2, "<!-- CONTENT_STYLE_GRABBER_END -->")); 

    if(!isset($_GET["ajax"]))
    {
        $css_include = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.vhb.wiwi.uni-wuerzburg.de/bp1/wp/wp-content/plugins/thrive-visual-editor/editor/css/thrive_flat.css">';
        echo $css_include;
    }

    echo "<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />";
    echo utf8_decode($content_style);
    echo utf8_decode($content);
}

?>
```

I tried some solutions posted on similar questions, but nothing worked out so far. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Seems like CORS issue, you are trying to make request to another domain, this is what you can not resolve from here..